# Find Point on the line segment (7/8) of the way connecting points P and Q

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

with $P = (4,3,-4)$ and $Q = (5,-4,3)$.
My thinking is take the distance between the two, which is $(1,-7,7)$ and taking $7/8$ of it which is $(-7/8,-49/8,49/8)$. But I feel like that is wrong and I have to then subtract that from $P$ or something.

Or I was thinking I have to normalize this result and work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, but you made one minor mistake in the sign when you multiplied by $7/8$. You should get $$\left(\frac{7}{8},-\frac{49}{8},\frac{49}{8}\right)$$

Then, you should add this to $P$, to get

$$\left(\frac{32}{8},\frac{24}{8},-\frac{32}{8}\right)+\left(\frac{7}{8},-\frac{49}{8},\frac{49}{8}\right) = \left(\frac{39}{8},-\frac{25}{8},\frac{17}{8}\right)$$

The leftmost summand above is just $P$ written with denominators of $8$.

Comment: My bad i actually mistyped point P, I'll fix it

Comment: @Tyler Okay it should be good now.

Comment: I believe your 33/8 value should be 17/8

Comment: @Tyler You are correct, I had not changed the $P$ value from the original one I saw.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** The segment joining the points $P$ and $Q$ is given by: $$X(t) = P + t(Q - P), \quad 0 \leq t \leq 1.$$
Notice that $X(0) = P$ and $X(1) = Q$. Make $t = 7/8$ and [be happy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oo4OnQpwjkc).